# What mill would you recommend to grind allspice?

Tags: equipment, pepper, milling

I recently buy allspice berries thinking that IKEA grinders could grind it. However, the berry is just too large to this mill.

What type of mill or grinding appliance should I be looking for when I need to grind allspice?

Comment: Most grinders are meant for peppercorns.  There are ones out there for coffee that I suspect would work for allspice unless you’ve got a goal strain that’s larger than a typical coffee bean

Answer (score 8):

I use a [mortar and pestle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortar_and_pestle) without any problems.  It also works for other spice seeds and is good for garlic, basil, etc.

Comment: I've been known to break them up a bit with the pestle and mortar, then finish the job with a pepper mill (I wanted fine+even)

Answer (score 4):

I have a [coffee grinder](https://www.target.com/p/krups-electric-spice-and-coffee-grinder-f2034251/-/A-52731838?ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&fndsrc=tgtao&DFA=71700000012576704&CPNG=PLA_Appliances%2BShopping%7CAppliances_Ecomm_Home&adgroup=SC_Appliances&LID=700000001170770pgs&LNM=PRODUCT_GROUP&network=g&device=c&location=9005787&targetid=aud-1289682520067:pla-797446485783&ds_rl=1246978&ds_rl=1248099&ds_rl=1247068&gclid=CjwKCAjw3riIBhAwEiwAzD3TiQakzoqAQDgbpoLzmWzsbYtsAnRBlogeixRkT-bta0Bg5BrOcE9BCxoCBPQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) that is dedicated only for whole spices.  It's faster than grinding by hand.  I just knock it out in the sink and wipe out with a cloth when I am finished.

Answer (score 0):

Third alternative: an [Indian Food Grinder](https://mykitchenculture.com/small-appliances/blenders/best-mixer-grinders-for-indian-cooking/). I own one; it's capable of grinding any spice, including super-woody ones like dried galangal. Only makes sense if you're grinding a lot of spices often, though.